# How can I implement a junction index in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Given two DynamoDB tables: Books and Words, how can I create an index that associates the two?  Specifically, I'd like to query to get all Books that contain a certain Word, and query to get all Words that appear in a specific Book.
The objective is to avoid scanning an entire table for these queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question I can't tell if you only care about unique words or if you want every word including duplicates. I'll assume unique words.

This can be done with a single table and a Global Secondary Index.

Create a table called BookWords with a Hash key of `bookId` and a Sort key of `word`. If you Query this table with a `bookId` you will get all of the unique words in that book.

Create a Global Secondary Index with a Hash key of `word` and a Sort key of `bookId`. If you Query this index with a `word` you will get all of the `bookIds` of books that contain that word.

Depending of your use case, you will probably want to normalize the words. For example, is "Word" the same as "word"?

If you want all words, not just unique words, you can use a similar approach with a few small changes. Let me know

Comment: thanks for that insight.  I've processed the words already - lowercase, correcting common misspellings, eliminating noise words, and reducing each one to its lemma. Your answer will allow me to explore the relationships in either direction - particularly to allow me to access other book information using the bookID.  Very helpful!

Comment: Happy I could help!